# How to open eml files?

Tags: software-recommendation, email

I've got a mail with `eml` file attached. I'm using Thunderbird but it doesn't open it.

Could anybody suggest program to open `eml` files?

Update:

I don't want to import my mailbox I want only read the content of `eml` file.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I saved attachment after I opened with **File->Open Saved Messages...** menu in Thunderbird.

Answer (score 58):

I found that these [instructions to be very helpful](https://mvtechjourney.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/ubuntulinux-open-eml-file-without-thunderbirdbkmailevolution/)

For the love of command line tools, instead of the visual/heavy Thunderbird/KMail or Evolution.

```
sudo apt-get install mpack
```

Then to extract the eml contents

```
munpack 1.eml
```

In my case I need to use -t to get past the following error messages

```
munpack ./ServerPerformance.eml 
tempdesc.txt: File exists
image001.jpg.2 (image/jpeg)
```

I then get every thing out like this.

```
munpack -t ./ServerPerformance.eml 
part1 (text/plain)
part2 (text/html)
image001.jpg.3 (image/jpeg)
```

Comment: can you put together a few eml's as an mbox with munpack?

Answer (score 23):

If you have Chromium you can drop eml files on it and it will show properly. 
On my Raspbian Chromiun is default.

Comment: Doesn't work here (assuming it also works in chrome..)

Answer (score 6):

You can open an `.eml` file simply with **Thunderbird** these days. No plug-in necessary.

`sudo apt-get install thunderbird`

In Thunderbird you can view it, print it, reply/forward/redirect, etc.

Go to *File* -> *Open* -> *Saved Messages...* or just double-click on an `.eml` file and select *Open With...* -> *Thunderbird*.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [MHonArc](https://www.mhonarc.org/) (*what* a website ) to convert the `.eml` files to HTML, if you want something command-line-y but `pandoc` isn't working out for you (it didn't for me):

```
sudo apt install mhonarc
mhonarc -single file.eml > file.html
```

Comment: How to include images in the converted HTML with `mhonarc`?

Answer (score 3):

- Save the .eml file in any place in your computer.
- Install this plug-ins [here](http://nic-nac-project.de/~kaosmos/mboximport-en.html). (see important note you can import EML files in IMAP accounts).

  To install the extension, follow this procedure:

  - download the xpi file that you find in this page or in the homepage, right clicking on the link and choosing "Save target as";
  - in Thunderbird, go in "Tools" ➜ "Addons" (or "Extensions") and click on "Install";
  - pick the xpi file you downloaded and follow the instructions;
- Restart Thunderbird.
- Go to Tools ➜ ImportExportTools ➜ Import eml File and find your file.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue in my company: one operator was forwarding a mail using Windows 10 Mail software and the other operator was unable to open the attached .eml file with Thunderbird.

Simply let Thunderbird re-forward the message back to the Thunderbird operator, like if you're forwarding the message to yourself, fixed the issue, actually i was able to see every attachment of the original message plus the true .eml file content.